# How to get inputs from an authentication failed on spring

Tags: authentication, spring-security

As my project migrated from SPRING 3 to SPRING 5 the methods I had to get the user credentials with AuthenticationException getAuthentication.getPrincipal() became deprecated and now I can't get the info when a user fails to authenticate.
I tried to get the info from the HttpServletRequest with request.getParameter(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION); but as my authentication object is already null I get null;
I also tried with request.getSession().getAttribute(name); but the code doesn't recognize the "name" variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring security authentication: get username without SPRING\_SECURITY\_LAST\_USERNAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052860/spring-security-authentication-get-username-without-spring-security-last-userna)

Answer (score 0):

I could get the info needed with request.getparameter("name of your variable"); Here is an exemple;

```
public void onAuthenticationFailure(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException {
   
   request.getparameter("name");
   request.getparameter("lastname");
   request.getparameter("id");
}
```